# App slow to open on device

Tags: ios, launching-application, launch-screen

I've been developing several apps and there's this situation that I can't quite figure out why. I'm using my development provision to build and run app on my device and it takes quite a while to open it. By 'open' I mean when I tap on the app icon, it gets greyed out for more than 10 seconds before the launch screen of the app shows up.

I thought this must due to the development provision, but then after I built my app for beta testing on TestFlight, I opened the beta version and it's still slow like the development version. Is anybody encountering the same issue? What could probably be the reason of this? Please suggest.

P.s: I believe this is not an issue of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method because I don't do anything there. Plus, as stated above, the launch screen is slow to show up, not the initial views of the app.

Comment: And what about app delegate functions..? Doing anything there too..?

Comment: Is it on every launch or just the first one? Also does it do it if you create an empty Xcode project and launch that?

Comment: Have you tried the app on other devices? Have you profiled the app using Instruments? How big is the application?

Comment: Are you running short of storage space on the device?

Comment: be careful with methods in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or applicationDidBecomeActive.

Comment: Does it happens only on one device? Did you try other devices? Opening other apps on that device, how do they behave?

Comment: Can you create a minimal project that reproduces this behavior? Debugging this without seeing any code is like trying to fix a car engine through the radio dials.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the suggestions. I tried with an empty project and the problem persists. I have tried debugging on an iphone 6 plus once and it wasn't slow like this. So I guess it's my device, there's 4gb free storage on it so I'm not sure it's the storage problem, @Fogmeister . Plus, how come this only happens to the apps I develop, not any other apps that I downloaded from app store?